# Split found files to run find -exec commands in parallel

Tags: command-line, find, batch

I have a multi-level directory of jpegs that I want to optimise on a semi-regular basis (as things are added). The command I'm using `jpegoptim` is single-threaded so when I run the following, only one CPU core is engaged and it takes a long time.

```
find media -exec jpegoptim --strip-all {} +
```

Given there are so many files and I have 8 CPU threads available, can I split the workload so it's running on all of them?

Comment: `find media -print0 | xargs -L1 -0 -P0 jpegoptim --strip-all` Magic.